# How to implement unnamed parameters

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I have an issue.

```
void setName(const string&);
```

How can i implement the code above? I need to write `this.name = ...` but there is no named variable. There is only `&` symbol.

Comment: What's stopping you from adding one?

Comment: You simply give it a name in the implementation: `void setName(const string& s) { /* .... */ }`

Comment: because i have a header file and i cant change it.

Comment: @AnılA Then you're SOL, because if it doesn't have a name, you can't use it. Are you able to modify the cpp implementation of that function? You can give the variable a name there. It doesn't have to match the header.

Comment: He can simply name it in the definition. However, his restriction is clearly stupid and too localized. Also, he won't get far with `this.name` in C++

Comment: so you are saying i will write that; void setName(const string& name){ this.name = name;} ?

Comment: it is not my restriction its my teacher's restriction bro

Comment: @AnılA: That would be `this->name` since `this` is a pointer; but yes, you can give the parameter a name when you define the function.

Comment: @AnılA: That would be `void setName(const std::string& new_name){name = new_name;}`.  There is no need to use `this->` if you choose different parameter name than member name.

Comment: @AnılA: That does not make it not terrifically stupid or too localized.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to include explicit parameter names in a function prototype. In fact, some programmers deliberately omit them.

Only when you *define* a function do you need to supply a parameter name, and only then if you actually *refer* to that parameter.

So in the header, `void setName(const string&);` is fine. This is telling you that the function takes a reference to a `string` (the `&` denotes a reference), and does not return anything.

But when you define the function, you'll need to supply a parameter if you refer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your header file has this...

```
class MyClass
   {
   string name;
public:
   void setName(const string&);
   };
```

Your implementation file can have this...

```
void MyClass::setName(const string& s )
   {
   this->name = s;
   }
```